# Binding value of one dependency property to another

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I created a custom control that derives from `Slider` and I am calling that control in an other user control as follows

```
<Custom:CustomSlider
            x:Name="CustomSlider"
            Minimum="0"
            Value="{Binding SliderCurrentValue,Mode=TwoWay}"
            SliderDictionaryValues="{Binding CustomSlider.DictionaryToBrSlider,Mode=TwoWay}"
            SliderValues="{Binding SliderCurrentValue,Mode=TwoWay}"></Custom:CustomSlider>
```

The `SliderDictionaryValues` and `Slider` values are both dependency properties in that Custom Control and its never being Set. Please help.

The `DictionaryToBrSlider` is a dependency property as follows in the code behind of my place where I am calling the custom `Slider` Control

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DictionaryToBRSliderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DictionaryToBrSlider", typeof(Dictionary<string, double>), typeof(BRSliderUserControl),new PropertyMetadata(null,DictionaryChanged));




public Dictionary<string, double> DictionaryToBrSlider
    {
        get { return (Dictionary<string, double>)GetValue(DictionaryToBRSliderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DictionaryToBRSliderProperty, value); }
    }


    private static void DictionaryChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
     //The break point hits here fine,.
    }
```

Here is my Custom Slider class.

```
public class CustomSlider : Slider
    {

        public Dictionary<string, double> SliderDictionaryValues
        {
            get { return (Dictionary<string, double>)GetValue(SliderValuesDictionaryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SliderValuesDictionaryProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SliderValues.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderValuesDictionaryProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SliderDictionaryValues", typeof(Dictionary<string, double>), typeof(CustomSlider), 
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSliderDictionaryPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnSliderDictionaryPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        { //BREAKPOINT NEVER HITS THIS LINE
            if (e.OldValue != e.NewValue && e.NewValue != null)
            {
                if (CustomTickBar.FontTextList == null)
                {
                    CustomTickBar.FontTextList = new List<string>();
                }
                Dictionary<string, double> NewValues = e.NewValue as Dictionary<string, double>;
                foreach(var item in NewValues)
                {
                    CustomTickBar.FontTextList.Add(item.Key);
                }
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderValuesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SliderValues", typeof(int), typeof(CustomSlider),
                new PropertyMetadata(0, OnSliderValueChanged));



        public int SliderValues
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(SliderValuesProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SliderValuesProperty, value);
            }
        }

        private static void OnSliderValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //public double CurrentSelectedValue
        //{
        //  get { return SliderValues.ElementAt(1).Value; }
        //}
    }
```

Comment: Why negative vote. Care to explain?

Comment: Maybe your bindings are incorrect. Have you checked the output console for Binding errors? What is the DataContext for those bindings in the first code snippet? Can you elaborate on "the code behind of my place where I am calling the custom Slider Control"? That phrase doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `DataContext` of the control to the parent `UserControl`:

```
<Custom:CustomSlider
            x:Name="CustomSlider"
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            Minimum="0"
            Value="{Binding SliderCurrentValue,Mode=TwoWay}"
            SliderDictionaryValues="{Binding DictionaryToBrSlider, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SliderValues="{Binding SliderCurrentValue, Mode=TwoWay}"></Custom:CustomSlider>
```

Comment: As everyone suggested the data context is the issue. Let me try setting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SliderDictionaryValues="{Binding ElementName=CustomSlider, Path=DictionaryToBrSlider, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Unless the DataContext is inherited from somewhere else, the source object of the binding was not being set. As counter-intuitive as this is, the default binding source is not the object itself. There is no default.